# pandas drop_duplicates and retain value closest to reference time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pd.DataFrame` with the following structure:

```py
$ df.head()
        target             refTime        name   latitude   longitude  
0          5.0 2020-05-31 22:48:00        YMLT -41.529999  147.190002   
1          6.0 2020-05-31 22:51:00        YWGT -36.419998  146.300003   
2          6.0 2020-05-31 22:56:00        YMAY -36.060001  146.929993   
3          5.0 2020-05-31 22:47:00        SUMU -34.830002  -56.000000   
4          3.0 2020-05-31 22:46:00        FACT -33.990002   18.600000   
5          5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00        SGES -25.450001  -54.849998   
6          5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00        SGAS -25.250000  -57.520000
7          5.0 2020-05-31 22:59:00        SUMU -34.830002  -56.000000      
8          8.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00        NFFN -17.750000  177.449997   
9          7.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00        SBPS -16.430000  -39.080002   
10         7.0 2020-05-31 22:50:00        NSTU -14.330000 -170.720001
```

This is weather data recorded at various stations on May 31, 2020. There may be duplicate (station) names, e.g. `SUMU`. However, each duplicate has a different `refTime`.

**Question**: How do I **drop duplicate station records** while retaining the **observation closest to the "full" hour** (in this case, `23:00:00`)? For this particular example I would end up dropping row 3.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if they did indeed answer your question. I'd go with Jezraels for performance reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) for round values, subtract by `ref_time`, create absolute values by [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indices of minimal values, so possible select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
idx = (df["refTime"].dt.round("H").sub(df["refTime"]).abs()
                    .groupby(df['name'], sort=False).idxmin())
df = df.loc[idx]
print (df)
    target             refTime  name   latitude   longitude
0      5.0 2020-05-31 22:48:00  YMLT -41.529999  147.190002
1      6.0 2020-05-31 22:51:00  YWGT -36.419998  146.300003
2      6.0 2020-05-31 22:56:00  YMAY -36.060001  146.929993
7      5.0 2020-05-31 22:59:00  SUMU -34.830002  -56.000000
4      3.0 2020-05-31 22:46:00  FACT -33.990002   18.600000
5      5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SGES -25.450001  -54.849998
6      5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SGAS -25.250000  -57.520000
8      8.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  NFFN -17.750000  177.449997
9      7.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SBPS -16.430000  -39.080002
10     7.0 2020-05-31 22:50:00  NSTU -14.330000 -170.720001
```

**Details**:

```
print (df["refTime"].dt.round("H").sub(df["refTime"]))
0    00:12:00
1    00:09:00
2    00:04:00
3    00:13:00
4    00:14:00
5    00:00:00
6    00:00:00
7    00:01:00
8    00:00:00
9    00:00:00
10   00:10:00
Name: refTime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

---

```
print (idx)
name
YMLT     0
YWGT     1
YMAY     2
SUMU     7
FACT     4
SGES     5
SGAS     6
NFFN     8
SBPS     9
NSTU    10
Name: refTime, dtype: int64
```

Comment: much better and probably more perfomant than my answer, nice one as always

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `assign` with `dt.round`

the idea is to sort the values by their distance from the hour, we will then sort the values and `drop_duplicates` keeping the first instance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = (
    df.assign(
        hour_diff=(df["refTime"].dt.round("H") - df["refTime"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "m")
    )
    .sort_values("hour_diff")
    .drop_duplicates(subset=["name"], keep="first")
    .drop("hour_diff", axis=1)
)

print(df2)

    target             refTime  name   latitude   longitude
5      5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SGES -25.450001  -54.849998
6      5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SGAS -25.250000  -57.520000
8      8.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  NFFN -17.750000  177.449997
9      7.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SBPS -16.430000  -39.080002
7      5.0 2020-05-31 22:59:00  SUMU -34.830002  -56.000000
2      6.0 2020-05-31 22:56:00  YMAY -36.060001  146.929993
1      6.0 2020-05-31 22:51:00  YWGT -36.419998  146.300003
10     7.0 2020-05-31 22:50:00  NSTU -14.330000 -170.720001
0      5.0 2020-05-31 22:48:00  YMLT -41.529999  147.190002
4      3.0 2020-05-31 22:46:00  FACT -33.990002   18.600000
```

the distance measure will look like this :

```
df.assign(
         hour_diff=(df["refTime"].dt.round("H") - df["refTime"]) / np.timedelta64(1, "m")
        )

    target             refTime  name   latitude   longitude  hour_diff
0      5.0 2020-05-31 22:48:00  YMLT -41.529999  147.190002       12.0
1      6.0 2020-05-31 22:51:00  YWGT -36.419998  146.300003        9.0
2      6.0 2020-05-31 22:56:00  YMAY -36.060001  146.929993        4.0
3      5.0 2020-05-31 22:47:00  SUMU -34.830002  -56.000000       13.0 # we drop this
4      3.0 2020-05-31 22:46:00  FACT -33.990002   18.600000       14.0
5      5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SGES -25.450001  -54.849998        0.0
6      5.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SGAS -25.250000  -57.520000        0.0
7      5.0 2020-05-31 22:59:00  SUMU -34.830002  -56.000000        1.0 # we keep this one
8      8.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  NFFN -17.750000  177.449997        0.0
9      7.0 2020-05-31 23:00:00  SBPS -16.430000  -39.080002        0.0
10     7.0 2020-05-31 22:50:00  NSTU -14.330000 -170.720001       10.0
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use the pandas .drop_duplicates() function to remove all rows that are duplicates of another row.
In your case call df.drop_duplicates()

Comment: i'm aware of the pandas `drop_duplicates` function. my question (stated above) is _how_ to use this function to drop duplicate station records while retaining the observation closest to the "full" hour.